# Django concurrent get_or_create

Tags: python, mysql, django, transactions, atomic

I'm concerned about one thing.
Using Django 1.7 (MySQL in the most default installation) I'm making a POST to a Django REST Framework `APIView`.
Over there I'm doing a:

```
try:
    MyModel.objects.get(**some_kwargs)
except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
    MyModel.objects.custom_create(**some_kwargs)  # This also creates relative models
```

Now what will happen if I'll do plenty of concurrent requests?
As I guess you expect I want only the first concurrent request to create an object and any other should get the created one.

Am I ready to go thanks do Django? Have to study about isolation, transactions, atomicity? Or is it more about locking the table? How to (unit) test it?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not enough to avoid race conditions, as another request can create the model you intended to retrieve between `get()` and `custom_create()`. If uniqueness is enforced on a database level, your `custom_create()` method can fail with an `IntegrityError`. If it is not, your method is fine, but you cannot prevent duplicate entries due to race conditions.

Django provides the `get_or_create()` function. This safeguards against race conditions if uniqueness is enforced by your database. It uses the `create()` method, however, not your `custom_create()` method, so you'll have to override it if it is acceptable. Otherwise, you can checkout out the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L449) for `get_or_create()` and implement it yourself with your custom create method.

The core assumption of `get_or_create` is that uniqueness is enforced on a database level. Due to this enforcement, `create` fails if a race condition occurs, and `get_or_create` can fall back to fetching the object created during the race condition. If this enforcement is missing, the `create` doesn't  fail during a race condition, and a duplicate entry (with a different PK) will be created.

Comment: Still no luck :( Now I'm trying postgresql and the same effect (tried READ COMMITTED on MySQL also) and a simple `MyModel.objects.get_or_create` delivered by Django - sometimes it ok (only one create) and sometimes the second thread creates again then the third throws `MultipleObjectsReturned`. Testing with this: https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/05/26/testing-django-views-for-concurrency-issues/

Comment: @McAbra Do you enforce uniqueness on `**some_kwargs` on a database level? Otherwise, there is no sane way to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I just made a `unique_together` on all three attrs of that model and it did not helped, is that what you ment?

Comment: @McAbra Yes. And the code in your question never throws an `IntegrityError`!?

Comment: Yes. Didn't get an `IntegrityError` neither when using that `custom_create` or now when using default `get_or_create`. I'm doing those concurrent POST requests to a simple view and all I get is `MultipleObjectsReturned`.

Comment: `get_or_create` depends on the fact that `create` throws an `IntegrityError` when a race condition occurs, and resolves it by returning the object created first created during the race condition. The fact that your own method doesn't throw an `IntegrityError` indicates that there is something wrong with your database-level uniqueness constraints, that's why `get_or_create` can't prevent race conditions. Can you post your models, the data you use to create them and your `custom_create` models?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74493/discussion-between-mcabra-and-knbk).